# Terraform azure cli authentication in container

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I want to create container from which I will run my terraform commands. My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli
RUN apk add curl
ENV TERRAFORM_VERSION 0.12.21
RUN curl -sL https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/${TERRAFORM_VERSION}/terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip -o tf.zip \
  && unzip tf.zip \
  && mv terraform /sbin/ \
  && rm -rf tf.zip
```

My `main.tf` looks like:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version         = "~>1.44"
  subscription_id = "xxx"
}
provider "azuread" {
  version = "~>0.6.0"
}
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {}
}
```

What I usually do on my `Windows` host is `az login` and then

```
terraform init \
    -backend-config=storage_account_name=xxx \
    -backend-config=container_name=terraform-state \
    -backend-config=access_key="xxx" \
    -backend-config=key=app.tfstate
```

The problem is that when I do same inside the docker container run as follows `docker run --rm -ti <IMAGE_ID> bash` instead of successful initialization I get weird error like:

```
Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: storage: service returned error: StatusCode=403, ErrorCode=AuthenticationFailed, ErrorMessage=Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of 
Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
```

Is this somehow related to

Comment: just created [this](https://gist.github.com/4c74356b41/a6a9f09fe13d6a4f4abc7722e86e3f6e) dockerfile today, it worked fine, can you, perhaps, try it out?

Comment: Thanks for link @4c74356b41. Tried out but there is not difference. I get same error. Are you also using terraform azure cli authentication?

Comment: yeah, I'm using azure cli auth on that particular docker image. does this work for you using the same credentials outside of docker

Comment: yes I aws using azure cli auth for several months from my windows machine but once I try to run it from inside of the Docker container I get that error. So far I was not able to simulate that behavior outside the container.

Answer (score 1):

For some unknown reason everything started working once I used `ubuntu:18.04` image instead of `mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli` and installed `az` myself.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt update && apt install -y curl jq wget unzip ca-certificates gnupg lsb-release apt-transport-https 

# Install Azure CLI
COPY azure-cupi.pub /root/.ssh/azure-cupi.pub
RUN curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash
RUN curl -sL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc.gpg > /dev/null
RUN AZ_REPO=$(lsb_release -cs) && echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/ $AZ_REPO main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/azure-cli.list
RUN apt update && apt install -y azure-cli

# Install Terraform
ARG TERRAFORM_VERSION="0.12.22"
RUN cd /tmp && \
    wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/${TERRAFORM_VERSION}/terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip && \
    unzip terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip -d /usr/bin && \
    rm -rf /tmp/* && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && \
    rm -rf /var/tmp/*
```

I did not find the significant difference.